# Multi-threaded Event Handlers

Tags: c#, multithreading

Here is my single-thread code :

```
OnStart 
{
 FileSystemWatcher Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
 Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite |NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
 FileActionHandler ActionHandler = new FileActionHandler();
 Watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(ActionHandler.onCreate);
}

onCreate(object source,FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
 try
 {
 FileInfo file = new FileInfo (e.FullPath);
 String output = <FileName>File.Name + <FullPath>File.FullName + <FileSize>File.Length +  <CreationTime>File.CreationTime + <LastAccess>File.LastAccess + <LastWriteTime>File.LastWriteTime;
 LogToTextFile(output);
 }
 catch
 {
 LogToTextFile(ex.GetBaseException().Message);
 }
}

private void LogToTextFile(String s)
{
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\Log.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
sw.WriteLine(s);
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
fileStream.Close();
}
```

Question: I want to incorporate Multi-Threading for Event-Handling in C# ? `Simply,what I mean is to start a new thread to handle for each of the events raised.`
 How do I go about doing that ? Please help me on this pressing issue...

Comment: For what it is worth, multi-threading the code that you use in the question will absolutely never make the code faster. You will either succeed in writing to the file from multiple threads at once (which will result in mangled output) or all the the new threads will immediately block trying to get access to write to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using .NET 4, as Pierre-Luc mentioned, you can simply swap out his code for this:

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate{
    onCreate(source, e);
})).Start();
```

Or, if you would rather use a ThreadPool (which I would recommend in this case)...

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate{ onCreate(source, e); });
```

Comment: Dear Sir,thus after adding your new thread object,I just ask the thread to do the remaining work of getting the file properties? Will this also means that I will be starting a new thread for processing information on every event raised ?

Comment: Correct... this is actually the fastest solution. Using the ThreadPool is not as fast, as there is a 0.5 second delay giving to ensure that a new thread need not be used... but that has a benefit of resource management.

Comment: I am afraid to discover that my CPU is peaking @ 100% after I incorporated the new thread thingy in my service.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a little snippet to create a task everytime you receive your event and multi-thread your event handler:

```
Watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(onCreateMultiThreaded);

onCreateMultiThreaded(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => onCreate(source, e));
}
```

Here's a shorthand for the thread pool solution:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s => onCreate(source, e));
```

Using the thread pool will allow you to reuse threads instead of creating new ones each time, this will make your application faster (removing the overhead of creating new threads.)

Comment: Do you have an alternative suggestion because my above application is targeted for .NET Framework 3.5 ?

Comment: Derek, please see my response below for pre-.net4 options.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions sir,I am trying out the solutions to see the differences,and I will keep you updated for any enquires,problems.

Comment: I am afraid to discover that my CPU is peaking @ 100% after I incorporated the new thread thingy in my service